# Google Analytics API returning no data before 23/09/16

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a Google Analytics API request that provides full data for any date after 23/09/16, but nothing before.

The metrics/dimensions in use are:

- date
- ga:sessions
- ga:users
- ga:deviceCategory
- ga:sourceMedium
- ga:campaign

I have created a custom report with the same dimensions/metrics in the web view, and I can confirm that the data does exist there (and is being provided). If I take out deviceCategory (or only have deviceCategory) then results are returned. This suggests to me that before this date, deviceCategory and sourceMedium/campaign were an invalid combination, but I can't find anything in the release notes to suggest this was changed and checking previous versions of the dimension explorer using archive.org does not indicate this was the case either.

I have raised a support request with Analytics support but they have said they don't have a team for API related issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. We already have a lot of reporting built around this combination and would like to be able to compare historical data.

Edit: I think this has something to do with the data retention settings in Analytics (which default to 26 months). Not sure why this particular combination would be affected as there is no user or event data required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it's because of data retention settings.

"The retention period applies to user-level and event-level data associated with cookies, user-identifiers <...>"

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7667196?hl=en

`deviceCategory` is associated with `ClientID`.